# Compartilhar token de acesso de Web API em diferentes dominios

Tags: javascript, rest, asp.net-web-api

Olá.

Estou com uma dificuldade em compartilhar um token de acesso (bearer) com domínios diferentes. Isso acontece, pois tenho que fazer uma página de login por fora do domínio do site que consome a API REST. Esse site mantém o token no localStorage, que não é cross-domain. Alguma sugestão para que, por fora do domínio, eu consiga 'jogar' esse token para um domínio específico?

Obs.: Por **GET** foi a única forma que consegui, mas não queria que fosse passado pela URL.

Comment: E por que não? O Facebook faz isso.

Comment: Bom, sem ser por uma requisição igual você comentou (que não é a melhor forma), você precisa fazer um servidor web clusterizado para que a sessão do usuário fique disponível para todos os servidores. Já adianto falando que não é uma implementação fácil de ser feita.

Comment: Imagino que não.
O fato de não poder ser por GET é por conta de cópias que podem ser feitas pelo usuário. Assim uma pessoa pode acessar a conta de outra, caso o usuário não faça o logout.